# Read values from <sampleSection>

Tags: c#, xml

I am using the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/aa903350(v=vs.71)) to build a configuration file with multiple values inside instead of key:value pattern.
This is the code I have in my App.config:

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="sampleSection"
               type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
   </configSections>
   <sampleSection setting1="Value1" setting2="value two" 
                  setting3="third value" />
</configuration>
```

How do I read the values inside `sampleSection` (setting1, setting2, etc)?

Comment: Did you get as far as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/aa903358(v%3dvs.71)? That article describes how to handle the `sampleSection` you created when using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ck3fs1(v=vs.71).

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: What version of dot net are you using? Json config seems to be on trend now...

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can access them

```
var nvc = ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("sampleSection") as NameValueCollection;
var setting1 = section["setting1"];
var setting2 = section["setting2"];    
var setting3 = section["setting3"];
```

or

```
var nvc= ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sampleSection") as NameValueCollection;
var setting1 = section["setting1"];
var setting2 = section["setting2"];    
var setting3 = section["setting3"];
```

Hope it helps.